# Lie algebra with $\sim \!N^3$ generators

Tags: mathematics, lie-algebra, deformation-quantization

Is there a Lie algebra whose number of generators scales as $N^3$, or in general $N^p$ with $p$ an arbitrary positive integer?

All the familiar examples, such as $\mathrm{U}(N)$ or $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ or $\mathrm{O}(N)$, have $N^2$ scaling.

Of course, yes, one might redefine  $N$. But I'm wondering whether there is something like a higher dimensional analog of the isomorphism $\mathrm{U}(\infty) \cong \mathrm{Diff}(\mathrm{T}^2)$ [1]. This isomorphism works roughly because the $N^2$ generators of $\mathrm{U}(N)$ correspond to $N^2$ number of points of a discretized torus $\mathrm{T}^2$. Is there an analog for $\mathrm{T}^p$ of generic $p$?

To elaborate on the discretization, the construction of $\mathrm{U}(\infty) \cong \mathrm{Diff}(\mathrm{T}^2)$ can be traced back to the Moyal deformation of the 2d diffeomorphism algebra that arises from the noncommutative torus. Hence, to put it differently, is there such a star product deformation of diffeomorphism Lie algebra for higher dimensions, satisfying the Jacobi identity?

[1] J. Hoppe, Diffeomorphism groups, quantization and $SU(∞)$, Int. J. Mod. Phys. A 04, 5235 (1989).

Comment: Paul Fletcher, in his Durham 1989 [thesis project](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(90)90300-U) shows there isn't--for all practical purposes. Of course, you know from the above classical semi simple algebras you've listed above, there are no such, but I assume you are gearing to stretch beyond semisimple...

Comment: With a heavy heart, I'd send you to [Ramos et al 1990](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528678), provided you appreciate *why* its results are *really* negative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short [FFZ 1989](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(89)91418-4) paper identifies the integral modes of the Moyal algebra on the 2-torus with SU(N), the classical semi-simple Lie Algebras (their O(N) and Sp(N) subalgebras are included in the longer paper, [FFZ 1990](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528788) ). You then find that, as you already know, semi-simple Lie Algebras must grow in dimension as $N^2$.

But, if you wish to forfeit semi-simplicity, you may limit yourself by the sky, since there are a zillion and one Kac-Moody constructions which carry inner generator labels ***which do not appear in the structure constants of them in the algebra***. You simply stick extra indices to the generators, to xerox  them indefinitely, to $N^3$, $N^4$, ..., trivially.

Here is one, satisfying the Jacobi identity, discussed in ¶4 of that first paper, restricting to *d*=3, the  3-torus,
$$
[K_{\mathbf m},K_{\mathbf n}]={\mathbf v}\cdot ({\mathbf m}\times {\mathbf n}) ~ K_{{\mathbf m}+ {\mathbf n}}.
$$
You might think there are $N^3$ generators, but a rotation in the 3-lattice  aligns ${\mathbf v}$ into the first component, $(v_1,0,0)$, ensuring that the first component of the generator index vectors, $(m_1,n_1)$, does not enter into the structure constants: it is an inert Kac-Moody index stacking up identical algebras. Calling the first components *(i,j)* and thus restricting **m,n** now to 2-torus indices, you have
$$
[K^i_{\mathbf m},K^j_{\mathbf n}]= {\mathbf m}\times {\mathbf n} ~ K_{{\mathbf m}+ {\mathbf n}}^{i+j},
$$
a mere $SU(N)\times {\mathbb Z}_N$ nascent Kac-Moody, as outlined in that paper.

Same for *d*-dimensional index vectors as described, with their determinant generalizing the cross product. So, only the *d*=2 case is outlined in the paper. For over 30 years people have been looking for nontrivial generalizations, which invariably deconstruct to trivial constructions: the  quiddity of star products.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this detailed answer and the overview on the subject! Could that "$\mathrm{SU}(N) \times \mathbb{Z}_N$ nascent Kac-Moody" make any contact with 3d diffeomorphisms in the large-$N$ limit?

Comment: Also, is there an intuitive argument that explains why 2d (area-preserving) diffeomorphisms are so special, admiting a deformation to a nontrivial group?

Comment: a) Not really, the structure constants are of a very special form, a small subclass of 3d diffeos...   b) Impossible to answer.... studying such cases on sees the logic and accepts the facts as "intuition"... Perhaps [this talk](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9tahoe.pdf)...

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time responding and the nice references! So the upshot is that the question of realizing the diffeomorphism group $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathcal{M}_d)$ (with possibly some conditions imposed, such as volume-preserving) in dimensions $d>2$ as a large-N limit of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra with $N^d$ generators (possibly a direct sum) is a not well-explored region of mathematics / mathematical physics.

Comment: I think this question has many important physical implications, so it is worth pursuing and investigating these infinite-dimensional Lie algebras. For instance the connection to strings mentioned in your article.

Comment: For the 3d I tried deforming the Nambu bracket, but it gives me a triple-argument bracket $[\,\,\,,\,\,\,,\,\,\,]$ and thus a "tripod structure constant" $f^d{}_{abc}$, while I want $f^c{}_{ab}$. Of course, it is a well-known fact that putting a constant function $f$ in the Nambu bracket as $[\,\,\,,\,\,\,,f]$ defines a Poisson bracket. This will correspond to something like $f^c{}_{ab} := f^c{}_{abd} v^d$, and I guess it gives the "restriction of 3d diffs" mentioned in your answer.